# ASP.NET: HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

How can I check what content has been sent by or buffered into a Response in my HttpModule?

Answer (score 5):

You look directly at the Response.OutputStream property maybe. If you wanted to actually modify the output, the best thing would be to write an implementation of stream and set it to Response.Filter

Good luck